# Restangular customPOST image file as Content-Type:multipart/form-data to NodeJS(Server)

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, image, restangular

**In Html:**

I just capturing an image snap from the webcam video using **web-directive** in **angularjs** and displayed the image in canvas tag,

```
<webcam on-stream="onStream(stream,video)" on-streaming="onSuccess(video)"></wevcam>
<canvas id="snapshot"></canvas>
```

**In Controller:**

Is this a right way of converting a image file from the canvas preview image(which is a base64 img),

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("#snapshot");
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

How to POST the image file to server using Restangular customPOST with Content-Type: multipart/form-data and how to GET this image file from server side?

Answer (score 0):

try this to get a file from server:

```
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("POST","url");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", " multipart/form-data");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",'POST','GET');
    xmlhttp.send();
```